# Spark glob filter to match a specific nested partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, glob

I'm using Pyspark, but I guess this is valid to scala as well
My data is stored on s3 in the following structure

```
 main_folder
└──  year=2022
   └──  month=03
      ├──  day=01
      │  ├──  valid=false
      │  │  └──  example1.parquet
      │  └──  valid=true
      │     └──  example2.parquet
      └──  day=02
         ├──  valid=false
         │  └──  example3.parquet
         └──  valid=true
            └──  example4.parquet
```

(For simplicity there is only one file in any folder, and only two days, in reality, there can be thousands of files and many days/months/years)

The files that are under the valid=true and valid=false partitions have a completely different schema, and I only want to read the files in the valid=true partition

I tried using the glob filter, but it fails with `AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.` which is a symptom of having no data (so no files matched)

`spark.read.parquet('s3://main_folder', pathGlobFilter='*valid=true*)`

I noticed that something like this works
`spark.read.parquet('s3://main_folder', pathGlobFilter='*example4*)`
however, as soon as I try to use a slash or do something above the bottom level it fails.
`spark.read.parquet('s3://main_folder', pathGlobFilter='*/example4*)`
`spark.read.parquet('s3://main_folder', pathGlobFilter='*valid=true*example4*)`

I did try to replace the * with ** in all locations, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

pathGlobFilter seems to work only for the ending filename, but for subdirectories you can try below, however it may ignore partition discovery. To consider partition discovery add basePath property in load option

```
spark.read.format("parquet")\
.option("basePath","s3://main_folder")\
.load("s3://main_folder/*/*/*/valid=true/*")
```

However I am not sure if you can combine both wildcarding and pathGlobFilter if you want to match based on both subdirectories and end filenames.

Reference:
https://simplernerd.com/java-spark-read-multiple-files-with-glob/
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html